# how add new address form data is inserted to database on form submit in onestepcheckout magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

In onestepcheckout page if a user has saved addresses then the saved addresses are shown in a select box with an additional option of "Add new address". Screenshot
[image]

I am using Idev->Onestepcheckout extension. "Enable AJAX save billing" option is made yes from admin panel.

Now my problem is when I click on saved addresses and check chrome's network tab then I can see a action being hit i.e. save_billing.
This action has the code for submitting the selected address to database.

Now If I select add new address option then I get a form where I can fill new address. This form is now submitted at the last after all the options are selected such as payment_method and shipping_method.
But I could not locate the code how this form's data is submitted to database.
My form action is "https://example.com/onestepcheckout/" .
I checked index action of index controller in onestepcheckout module but I could not find any code there which is responsible for saving the above data to database. Anyone could help me in finding how the form data is saved.

Comment: Please contact onestepcheckout.com support, the contact details are available on our website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onestepcheckout

block->checkout.php,

_handlePostData function is responsible for handling the form data and saving it to database.